# What does an "srrq" and "UVLO" block do in a block diagram on the datasheet?

Tags: datasheet, mosfet-driver, diagram, block-diagram

I have this datasheet here for a [FAN7392](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/301536/FAIRCHILD/FAN7392.html) .

In the block diagram section it has 2 parts and I have no idea what they do. I tried researching it online, but i'm not even really sure what I should search up to find the answer? Unfortunately I didn't find anything so i'm asking here.

What do the 2 blocks with the letters "SRRQ" and "UVLO" do in this diagram? I'm looking at the top half of the schematic because it's not working the way I want it to. If I apply a HIGH / LOW input into the HIN pin then it doesn't affect the voltage of the HO pin at all and i'm not sure why. Here is the schematic:

[image]

Comment: Just to re-enforce RussellH’s answer - the high side driver relies on the pwm signal for the boost voltage. This also places a constraint on the pwm frequency and duty cycle. Refer to the datasheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SRRQ refer to the inputs and outputs of a set-reset flip-flop. S-set R-reset (there are 2) Q out put 1 if set, 0 if reset,

UVLO under voltage lockout

The circuit with the blue high light is a standard high side driver used in ICs. The flip-flop switches at the PWM rate and holds the PWM state to prevent voltage droop. If VS is too low, the UVLO holds the high side in reset thus turning off the output transistors.

Comment: In a circuit like this, why would the reset pin ever trigger? Cause it’s pretty much just if you have a voltage applied to the input a voltage will come out right?

Comment: @Trev347: See the edit I added.